# Manually cache a special, non-WP-but-using-WP page (e.g. Ajax results) with W3TC

Tags: ajax, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, wp-load.php, autocomplete

Under the active theme folder, I have a search-autocomplete.php file which uses various WP queries to create smart JSON results delivered via AJAX to a jQuery UI Autocomplete input field. It's not a normal template file (in fact it shouldn't really be in the theme's folder, it could be a plugin), but it loads the needed WP functions with this line:

```
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
```

However, since it doesn't execute the normal hooks a full page executes, it will never be cached by W3TC or Super Cache, which is obviously suboptimal, especially for something that gets requested with almost every keypress on a search field.

Is there any way to manually tell W3TC via its API to cache this JSON and get it from the cache if appropriate?** Or should I go ahead and code my own caching mini-script for this kind of stuff?

Comment: I imagine it would be much easier if you were using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or an [endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) for this, then you would at least be operating within the context of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

No caching plugin will cache ajax request because it is considered a bad idea to cache a post request as they are usually used to change the state of the site and therefor might have a different response.

You will have to write such a caching by yourself.

Comment: It's not a POST request, it's a GET request just like the normal search results page.

Comment: better questions with full details -> better answers. This gets totally off-topic as each plugin may have its own different handling of get requests and as you know plugin specific questions are off-topic.